# Cant mount previously created XFS file system in Debian

Tags: linux, hard-drive, debian, mount, xfs

I am trying to mount a hard drive that has been previously used in another device that had the drive formatted as XFS. I have tried to research the error, but I cant find any solution to the exact problem I am facing.

Running `sudo blkid` shows the drive at `/dev/sdh*`

```
/dev/sdh1: UUID="a09d6417-3771-4ad5-a35d-90e8c5f8b3dd" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="xfs" PARTUUID="8db76c67-01"
/dev/sdh2: PARTUUID="8db76c67-02"
/dev/sdh5: UUID="061935cf-e4f9-4c03-8543-ae08e44ec4c5" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="xfs" PARTUUID="8db76c67-05"
/dev/sdh6: PARTUUID="8db76c67-06"
/dev/sdh7: TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="8db76c67-07"
/dev/sdh8: TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="8db76c67-08"
```

and running

```
sudo mount -t xfs /dev/sdh1 /mnt/data
```

gives the error

```
mount: /mnt/data: unknown filesystem type 'xfs'.
```

---

I have tried running `xfs_repair` on the drive but it errors out giving

```
Phase 1 - find and verify superblock...
xfs_repair: filesystem has a realtime subvolume
xfs_repair: realtime device init failed
xfs_repair: cannot repair this filesystem.  Sorry.
```

Does anyone know why I cant mount the drive?

Comment: [This answer on U&L SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/389782/108618) and the comments there. Does it help?

Comment: Thanks for the response, but unfortunatly not. I saw that article before and it was no help. After following the instructions for live mounting the drive, I still receive ```mount: /media/data: unknown filesystem type 'xfs'.```

Comment: So as per the U&L question you've confirmed that your xfs module is loaded? Because you shouldn't get the "unknown filesystem" message if it is loaded. Also it should auto-load, but I suspect it's not and figuring out why will lead to your answer.